# Terser keep (don't mangle) a specific function name

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, terser

Is there a way to not mangle only one function name?  A comment in the code would be easiest, but I guess this could be done by specifying a custom "nameCache" ?  But I don't know how that works.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure this out, but I already had the function name so I stored the function name on the webpage in an attribute that I could find later with JavaScript. e.g.

```js
function bob() {
  console.log('hello');
}

document.querySelector('#myid').setAttribute('data-function-name', bob.name);
```

```html
<span id="myid">for example make this style="display:none;"</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent **terser** from mangling a particular symbol, you need to add it to terser's reserved list.  This can be done in your terser options file:

```
{
    "mangle":
    { 
        "properties":
        {
            "reserved": ["symbolToNotMangle", "anotherSymbolToPreserve"]
        }
    }
}
```

If you are not already using a **terser** options file, you would save that off to (for example) terser_options.json and tell **terser** to use it like so:

```
terser ... --config-file terser_options.json
```

You can also just list the reserved symbols on the command line if you prefer:

```
terser ... -m reserved=['symbolToNotMangle','anotherSymbolToPreserve']
```

https://github.com/terser/terser#cli-mangle-options

Comment: It "works", but afterwards I only run into "undefined" errors... seems like it ignores mangling but then other symbols still refer to the mangled names.